Why does the "Next Run" date not correlate to the schedule for this SSRS subscription job?
I migrated a SQL Server Reporting Services v2012 server to a v2019 server and found afterwards that at least one report subscription is executing on a date which does not match the schedules that are configured.  After identifying the SQL Agent job for this subscription, I found that the "Last Run" and "Next Run" dates are completely wrong in SQL Job Activity Monitor, and these incorrect dates are determining (or at least match) the actual execution for the subscription.
Specifically, this job is scheduled to run at 3:05am on the 10th day of Jan, Apr, Jul, and Oct.  But it ran on Feb 10th.  The migration was in September of 2023.
Job Activity Monitor/Job Schedules
I already saw this question and verified that the schedule in the SSRS "Schedule" table is correct: Job Activity Monitor has incorrect Next Run
I was able to correct this issue by deleting and recreating the schedules in SSRS, but I would like to better understand what caused this so that I know what to look for in the future, or maybe even how to prevent it.
